# Como converter uma string em const char *?

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um reprodutor de áudio(um mp3 player) usando a biblioteca `SDL_mixer`.

O problema é que tenho uma função que retorna uma string (um diretório de uma música) que preciso passar essa string como argumento para a função `*Mix_LoadMUS(const char *file)`.

Sou iniciante em programação (1º período), serei grato se as respostas forem simplificadas.

Como faço para transformar uma string num tipo `const char*`?

Comment: Essa string é o tipo string do C++, ou é um tipo string de uma outra biblioteca? Se for o tipo do C++ padrão, acho que s.c_str() retorna um const char * compatível com C padrão.

Comment: A especificação "const char *file" é só para garantir que a função não modificará o conteúdo apontado pelo ponteiro file.

Comment: Estou usando somente C, essa string vem de uma função escrita com a biblioteca GTK, essa função é um (File_chooser) Tela onde o usuário escolhe o arquivo que quer abrir . Consigo visualizar o conteúdo da string imprimindo ela em uma arquivo (fprintf). O problema é que quando tento passar essa string para a outra função, o programa fecha.

Comment: É do tipo GString?

Comment: Coloca o trecho do codigo por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Se for GString do GTK+, use

```
astringemquestao->str
```

que aponta diretamente para o buffer contendo a string. Ele é terminado em nulo e pode ser usado onde um `const char *` é esperado.

Lembrando que: qualquer modificação na GString, o valor do membro str pode mudar. Portanto este ponteiro não deve ser reutilizado. Se você precisar ter acesso a string durante um intervalo de tempo maior, durante o qual a GString talvez mude, faça uma cópia e use a cópia, não esquecendo de liberar depois.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando uma string da std (std::string), chame a função c_str().

Por exemplo:

```
std::string str;

...

Mix_LoadMUS(str.c_str());
```

Comment: foi citado nos comentários que é usado apenas C.

Answer (score 0):

O qualificador **const** apenas indica que a variável não pode ser alterada.
Assim o código abaixo significa que os dados apontados pelo ponteiro file não são alteráveis:

```
void Processa(const char * file)
{
      ....
}
```

O compilador se encarrega de gerar um alerta de erro caso o código na rotina tente alterar o conteúdo apontado pelo ponteiro.
Notar que **const char *p** ou **char const *p** tem o mesmo significado, ou seja os dados apontados não são modificáveis. Mas **char * const p** quer dizer o ponteiro é constante, não podendo ser modificado.
Portanto não deve ser problema, você passar uma variável string sem qualificador const para uma rotina como a mostrada em sua pergunta.
[EDIT]
Relendo sua pergunta percebi que seu problema é que o parâmetro que você está tentando passar para a rotina está gerando o erro na hora de compilar, correto?
Se sim, teste usar `casting` para adequar o parâmetro ao exigido pelo rotina chamada, por exemplo assim:

```
   char *p = Mix_LoadMUS ( (const char *) file )
```